# Printing float with precision 2 but without decimal(.) in C++

Tags: c++

Please Consider Code snippet shown below:

```
// setprecision example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout.precision(2);

  std::cout << f*100 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is print on screen 314 (i.e. print f without decimal with precision as 2)

I want thinking of first setting precision as 2 and then multiplying with 100.

But it seems that precision is finally applied on f*100. Can anyone suggest of any way to apply precision on f  then to multiply the number by 100 and finally to print with precision 0?

Comment: multiply by 100 and apply precision 0?

Comment: You can't apply precision to a floating-point number. The type has the same precision no matter what. You can only change the precision for printing.

Comment: I did same..But i can't store data into another variable after multiplying with 100

Comment: @chris apply precision 0 *when printing*.

Comment: @MayankJain I think you are looking for `std::floor(f*100)` (from the `cmath` header). Edit: Actually, looking at one of your comments, I think you want `std::round(f*100)` from the same header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply by a 100 and print with precision 0.

```
int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout.precision(0);

  std::cout << std::fixed << f*100 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if f=3.14656 .. After applying precision answer should be 315 but in your case answer would be 314

Comment: @MayankJain No. It will output `315` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a "proper" way to do this, without having to alter the value at all.  You can prepare an `std::ostringstream` that will do this for you by using your own `std::numpunct` subclass:

```
#include <locale>

class no_decimal_punct: public std::numpunct<char> {
protected:
    virtual char do_decimal_point() const
    { return '\0'; }
};
```

You can now prepare an `std::ostringstream` that will use the above `no_decimal_punct` class:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ostringstream strm;
strm.imbue(std::locale(strm.getloc(), new no_decimal_punct));
strm.precision(2);
std::fixed(strm);

double f = 3.14159;
strm << f;
std::cout << strm.str() << '\n';
```

The advantage here is that you're not changing the value of `f`, which could potentially print something else than intended due to FP errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to display 314:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  const double PI = 3.1415926;
  cout.precision(3);
  cout<<PI * 100<<endl;
}

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  const double PI = 3.1415926;
  cout<<(int)(PI * 100)<<endl;
}
```